# Is there an official Ubuntu free technical support team?

Tags: support

I have found that there is an "Ubuntu Support Team" at https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-helpteam but I am not sure it's official or active.
Please note that I am not referring to bug fixing support, I am referring to the broader OS support, with people available to engage users needing support with a problem and drive it to a proper resolution.

Is there an official team for this purpose with a clear scope and activity plan ?

Comment: Honestly I don't know if that works. But I'm a long time Ubuntu user, and can tell you that getting support or relevant answers to questions/issues from forums is / *was* a pain. I say *was* because it seems the Ubuntu site from S.E. that I discovered recently does a good job at allowing people to get answers to their questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear the "Ubuntu Support Team" that you mentioned has been inactive for over two years. (In fact I don't think it was ever really 'active').

There are four main places to go for community support:

- IRC channel #ubuntu - personally I wouldn't advise it because it gets very chaotic
- [The Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/)
- [Launchpad Answers](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu)
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com)

You might want to take a look at [When should we use Launchpad Answers and when Ask Ubuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/675/when-should-we-use-launchpad-answers-and-when-ask-ubuntu). In my opinion none of these four tools are great for "troubleshooting", but this site is doing a very good job answering a lot of the questions people have about Ubuntu.

Comment: +1 - though I'd put it differently, the IRC channels are *wonderfully chaotic* ;-)

Comment: Is this still accurate? Also is cross posting across these places okay?